# Как присвоить значение указателю в массиве указателей C++

Tags: c++, указатели

Вот код моей программы:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int** a = new int*[10];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        a[i] = nullptr;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        *a[i] = i; //<========== на этом этапе ошибка
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << *a[i] << ' ';
    }
}
```

Программа вбрасывает исключение: `Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00B425AC в Main.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x00000000.`

Почему это происходит? Ведь я разыменовываю i-тый указатель и присваиваю ему значение, все же должно быть по идее нормально.

И как можно решить данную проблему, с учетом того, что мне нужно оставить массив указателей.

Comment: Сперва делаете так: `a[i] = nullptr;`, а потом так `*a[i] = i;` => результат предсказуем: "нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу **0x00000000**" Ещё не догадались, в чём суть проблемы?

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл изначально `a[i]` указатель указывает на `nullptr`, но потом я ему присваиваю значение. Значит он после этого должен указывать на значение , а не на `nullptr`?

Comment: Или он пытается в `nullptr` присвоить значение?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь по нулевому адресу записать некоторое значение.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл понял. Да, вы правы.

Comment: `delete/free()` для `nullptr/NULL` безопасно, а разыменование - нет.

Comment: Лучше используйте вектор смартпоинтеров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему вы не хотите выполнить все в одном цикле?

```
int** a = new int*[10];
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    a[i] = new int(i);
    cout << *a[i] << ' ';
    delete a[i];
}
delete[]a;
```

Comment: Тогда пропадёт смысл массива:)

Comment: А чего сразу не упростить до `cout << "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ";`? :D

Comment: @EOF, в этом учебном коде смысла в массиве и не было. Смысл  заключается в  понимании что к чему...

Answer (score -1):

Указатель в который я пытался положить значение указывал на `nullptr`, то бишь вникуда. И в это вникуда я пытался присвоить значение. Значит нужно просто выделить памяти для значения.

Код решения моей проблемы:

```
int main()
{
    int** a = new int*[10];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        a[i] = nullptr;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        a[i] = new int;
        *a[i] = i;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << *a[i] << ' ';
    }
}
```